# unable to spawn ssh using TCL expect in ActiveTCL

Tags: ssh, tcl

I am trying to ssh through .tcl script from ActiveState TCL 'tclsh' window.
Having WINDOWS OS system.

```
#!/bin/sh    
# \    
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}    
package require Expect


set user [lindex $argv 0]    
set password [lindex $argv 1]    
set DeviceIpAddr [lindex $argv 2]    
set DeviceHostName [lindex $argv 3]    

foreach DeviceIp $DeviceIpAddr HostName $DeviceHostName {    

    spawn ssh $DeviceIp     
     expect "login as:"    

    send "$user\r"    
    expect "Password:"    

    send "$password\r"    
    expect "$HostName ~]#"    
}
```

I see below error while execute in tclsh(ActiveTCL)

```
% tclsh Test.tcl root 321 17.250.217.151 lb02va    
The system cannot find the file specified.         
    while executing    
"spawn ssh  root@$DeviceIp"       
    ("foreach" body line 3)  
    invoked from within    
"foreach DeviceIp $DeviceIpAddr HostName $DeviceHostName {     

        spawn ssh  root@$DeviceIp           
        expect "login as:"     

        send "$user\r"    
        expect "Password:"     

        send..."    
    (file "Test.tcl" line 12)    
child process exited abnormally
```

Kindly assist me resolving this.
Thank you.

Comment: What operating system is this? Where is the `ssh` program installed? What is your command path? In other words, what is the value of the PATH environment variable? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I'd say the error message suggests `spawn` failed to spawn `ssh` because the OS failed to locate a program named "ssh" in the directories listed in the current user's `PATH` environment variable -- just what @Kenster said. Hence, the first thing to try out is to just run `ssh` at the same prompt you run your `tclsh` binary from -- it it does not work, the problem has nothing to do with Tcl but with basic knowledge of your OS.

Comment: I am new to this. How to find/set the value of PATH environment variable? I am trying to run from WINDOWS OS system.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have ssh installed. From the bash prompt (Mac, Linux, Cygwin) or cmd prompt (Windows), type:

```
ssh
```

If you see an error, try to fix it. The most likely cause is ssh not installed, or not in the path.

Next, in your script, you did not use the `$user` variable, instead you use the hard-coded `root`. Fix that:

```
spawn ssh $user@$DeviceIp
```

The final problem: you already specified the user name from the command line, the ssh program will not ask for user again, so you must delete these two lines:

```
expect "login as:"    
send "$user\r"
```

After that, hopefully everything will go as planned.