# Unable to spawn ssh using expect in ActiveTcl on Windows PC

Tags: ssh, expect, spawn, activetcl

The title is similar to [unable to spawn ssh using TCL expect in ActiveTCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122449/unable-to-spawn-ssh-using-tcl-expect-in-activetcl) but I think I'm running into a different problem...

I just installed the 32-bit version of ActiveTcl 8.5 on my Windows 10 PC.  After installing it, I successfully installed Expect by typing the following at the tcl command line:

```
teacup install Expect
```

While following a tutorial on how to use Expect to log into a remote machine, my code is failing when it tries to use the 'spawn' command.  I have reduced my code down to the following minimum lines in a script file called simple_ssh.tcl

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0"  ${1+"$@"}
package require Expect
spawn ssh eric@192.168.1.191
expect "eric@192.168.1.191's password:"
```

When I run this with the command `tclsh simple_ssh.tcl`, I get the error:

> The request is not supported.
>       while executing "spawn ssh eric@192.168.1.191"
>       (file "simple_ssh.tcl" line 5) child process exited abnormally

If I instead simply type `ssh eric@192.168.1.191` at the tcl prompt, the remote machine responds with the expected prompt:

```
eric@192.168.1.191's password:
```

And the ssh session operates as expected. So it can see the ssh process.  It seems to me that 'spawn' might not be properly integrated into Expect.  What else could I be doing wrong?  Is there another package I need to install as part of ActiveTcl to get this to work?

Comment: A more straightforward shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env tclsh`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
spawn "ssh eric@192.168.1.191"